# Sorting django-mptt record by complex string field as number

Tags: django, django-mptt

I'm using django-mptt to build a hierarchical structure. There is a field "task_id", that represents task id, in the following format "task.subtask.subtask", number of subtasks is infinite.

To sort tasks, I'm using standard code `order_insertion_by = ['task_id']`

It works well, but the fields are sorted as string, i.e. `1.10, 1.2, 1.3`, etc.

How can I make them sort as a number instead, so it will go `1.2, 1.2, 1.10`?

Comment: It looks like approach that you will use for standard model ordering doesn't work here

`ordering = [Cast('task_id', output_field=models.IntegerField()), ]`

raises the following error: `'Cast' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1):

Strings are lexicographically sorted, and `1.10` comes before `1.2`, so you'll need an `order_insertion_by` that's lexicographically sortable.

The simplest would be to pad `task_id`'s elements to e.g. 5 digits (if you can always trust you'll never have more than 99999 elements per level), and concatenate them since you know each element is always 5 digits long, you don't need separators, so the identifier could be e.g. `0000100010`, etc. (This is coincidentally pretty much what [django-treebeard's materialized path trees do](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mp_tree.html).)
You could also save some space by using e.g. base36 (0-9a-z) "numbers" instead, in which case e.g. you could use 4 characters for 36**4 = 1 679 616 options, or base62 (0-9a-zA-Z), etc.

Since [it looks like](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/blob/9483613443b65694cb8866d5d73b0e93fdce2413/mptt/managers.py#L141-L142) `order_insertion_by` needs to refer to a concrete field, you can't get by with a sortable Python property, so you'd need a new (computed, cached) field for that lexicographically sortable `task_id`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't wanted to create additional field, but it looks like that's the only way here.